# Function returns undefined with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

I am trying to wrap my head around the `isBreadwinner` function. Why does not `true` pass into the (**) function. Why is Earning member:undefined

```
<script>
    "use strict"

    //creating a user object 
    let user = {
        name : "Stackoverflow Developer",
        age : 23
    };

    // appending properties to the user object
    user.location = "NYC";
    user["occupation"] = "JavaScript Developer";
    user["salary"] = 10;

    //(**)
    let isBreadwinner = () => {
        (user.salary) ? true : false;
    };

    console.log("asd" + isBreadwinner());
    user["Earning member"] = isBreadwinner();

    // printing the object
    console.dir("User dir object" + JSON.stringify(user));
    console.dir(user); //Earning member:undefined
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the `return` in your `isBreadWinner` function.

```
let isBreadwinner = function() {
    return (user.salary) ? true : false;
};
```

If you want to skip using a `return` then you might want to use an ES6 arrow function which has implicit returns if everything is declared on one line without a block, `{}`.

`let isBreadwinner = () => (user.salary) ? true : false;`

Comment: return (user.salary) ? true : false; works but (user.salary) ? return true : return false; does not.

Comment: Please throw some light on the why the error pops up in  (user.salary) ? return true : return false;

Comment: Because it's not valid JavaScript syntax when using a ternary `if` statement. If you switch to a normal `if` statement then you can use your returns as you want.

Comment: Similarly let isBreadwinner = () => {
    (user.salary) ? true : false;
  }; does not work if multi line.

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the clarity

Comment: @lft93ryt it's not because it's multiline, it's the `{` `}`

Comment: If you said multi statement then I'd agree. But multiline is misleading

Answer (score 1):

you may write the function like this

```
let isBreadwinner = () => (user.salary) ? true : false;
```

or just add `return` to your function